# Re-initialize a lazy initialized variable in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a variable that initialized as:

```
lazy var aClient:Clinet = {
    var _aClient = Clinet(ClinetSession.shared())
    _aClient.delegate = self
    return _aClient
}()
```

The problem is, at some point, I need to reset this `aClient` variable so it can initialize again when the `ClinetSession.shared()` changed. But if I set the class to optional `Clinet?`, LLVM will give me an error when I try to set it to `nil`. If I just reset it somewhere in the code using `aClient = Clinet(ClinetSession.shared())`, it will end up with `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Is there a way that can use `lazy` and being allowed to reset itself?

Comment: Just because I stumbled reading the code: is it `Clinet` and `ClinetSession ` on purpose or is it a typo?

Comment: @luk2302 typo, but guess it wasn't stop people from solving my question after all. :)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

lazy is explicitly for one-time only initialization.  The model you want to adopt is probably just an initialize-on-demand model:

```
var aClient:Client {
    if(_aClient == nil) {
        _aClient = Client(ClientSession.shared())
    }
    return _aClient!
}

var _aClient:Client?
```

Now whenever `_aClient` is `nil`, it will be initialized and returned.  It can be reinitialized by setting `_aClient = nil`

Comment: This is clever! BTW I think we might needs to use `self._aClient` in the `get{}`. Sometimes Swift compiler can find a var in some cases if the `self.` is missing.

Comment: I had hoped for something better in Swift 2. What you really want is a var with a setter that only allows setting to nil, and getter code that is only called when the property is nil. Like var aClient:Client { setnil; getnil { aClient = Client (ClientSession.shared ()) } } getnil would be called if you get the variable after setting it to nil.

Comment: @gnasher729 Hooray for Swift 3! See my answer for exactly that :)

Comment: Nice Answer...This method worked nicely for setting the GMSCircle which I created as Lazy var initially..Thank you!

Comment: If you use var _aClient:Client! then you can more easily configure _aClient in the getter.

Answer (score 47):

Because [the behavior of `lazy` changed in Swift 4](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5172), I wrote a few `struct`s that give very specific behavior, which should never change between language versions. I put these on GitHub, under [the BH-1-PD](https://github.com/RougeWare/Swift-Lazy-Patterns/blob/master/LICENSE-GENERAL.txt) license: https://github.com/RougeWare/Swift-Lazy-Patterns

### [`ResettableLazy`](https://github.com/RougeWare/Swift-Lazy-Patterns/blob/master/Sources/LazyContainers/LazyContainers.swift#L251-L328)

Here is the one relevant to this question, which gives you a way to lazily-initialize a value, cache that value, and destroy it so it can be lazily-reinitialized later.

**Note that this requires Swift 5.1!** For the Swift 4 version, see [version 1.1.1 of that repo](https://github.com/RougeWare/Swift-Lazy-Patterns/tree/1.1.1).

The simple usage of this is very straightforward:

```swift
@ResettableLazy
var myLazyString = "Hello, lazy!"

print(myLazyString) // Initializes, caches, and returns the value "Hello, lazy!"
print(myLazyString) // Just returns the value "Hello, lazy!"

_myLazyString.clear()
print(myLazyString) // Initializes, caches, and returns the value "Hello, lazy!"
print(myLazyString) // Just returns the value "Hello, lazy!"

myLazyString = "Overwritten"
print(myLazyString) // Just returns the value "Overwritten"
_myLazyString.clear()
print(myLazyString.wrappedValue) // Initializes, caches, and returns the value  "Hello, lazy!"
```

This will print:

```
Hello, lazy!
Hello, lazy!
Hello, lazy!
Hello, lazy!
Overwritten
Hello, lazy!
```

If you have complex initializer logic, you can pass that to the property wrapper:

```swift
func makeLazyString() -> String {
    print("Initializer side-effect")
    return "Hello, lazy!"
}

@ResettableLazy(initializer: makeLazyString)
var myLazyString: String

print(myLazyString) // Initializes, caches, and returns the value "Hello, lazy!"
print(myLazyString) // Just returns the value "Hello, lazy!"

_myLazyString.clear()
print(myLazyString) // Initializes, caches, and returns the value "Hello, lazy!"
print(myLazyString) // Just returns the value "Hello, lazy!"

myLazyString = "Overwritten"
print(myLazyString) // Just returns the value "Overwritten"
_myLazyString.clear()
print(myLazyString.wrappedValue) // Initializes, caches, and returns the value  "Hello, lazy!"
```

You can also use it directly (instaed of as a property wrapper):

```swift
var myLazyString = ResettableLazy<String>() {
    print("Initializer side-effect")
    return "Hello, lazy!"
}

print(myLazyString.wrappedValue) // Initializes, caches, and returns the value "Hello, lazy!"
print(myLazyString.wrappedValue) // Just returns the value "Hello, lazy!"

myLazyString.clear()
print(myLazyString.wrappedValue) // Initializes, caches, and returns the value "Hello, lazy!"
print(myLazyString.wrappedValue) // Just returns the value "Hello, lazy!"

myLazyString.wrappedValue = "Overwritten"
print(myLazyString.wrappedValue) // Just returns the value "Overwritten"
_myLazyString.clear()
print(myLazyString.wrappedValue) // Initializes, caches, and returns the value  "Hello, lazy!"
```

These will both print:

```
Initializer side-effect
Hello, lazy!
Hello, lazy!
Initializer side-effect
Hello, lazy!
Hello, lazy!
Overwritten
Initializer side-effect
Hello, lazy!
```

---

This answer has been updated; its original solution no longer works in Swift 4 and newer.

Instead, I recommend you use one of the solutions listed above, or [@PBosman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39636313/3939277)

Previously, this answer hinged on behavior which was a bug. Both that old version of this answer, its behavior, and why it's a bug are described in the text and comments of [Swift bug SR-5172](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5172) (which has been resolved as of 2017-07-14 with [PR #10,911](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/10911)), and it's clear that this behavior was never intentional.

That solution is in that Swift bug's text, and also in [the history of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40847994/1), but because it's a bug exploit that doesn't work in Swift 3.2+ **I recommend you do *not* do that.**

Comment: IMHO, this is a cleaner way to achieve this than the accepted answer.

Comment: +1 for the usage of `!`, however, if one were to utilize this pattern, every caller of this variable would still have to unwrap the `Optional`. E.g., `print(aClient) // prints "Optional(Clinet)\n"`

Comment: @pxpgraphics Not in my experience... `class Foo { lazy var str: String! = "Bar" }; var foo = Foo(); print(foo.str)` should print `Bar`

Comment: I just tried it in a playground this morning, uploaded here: https://gist.github.com/pxpgraphics/4cfb7e02b6be7a583bf5f8a3ccbcd29a

So maybe this is related to the string interpolation :]

Comment: @pxpgraphics I hate Swift strings so much XD

Comment: Is this documented anywhere for swift 3?

Comment: @bencallis I can't find official documentation of this feature ([This seems to be all Apple has to say about `lazy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID257)), but tests prove it works reliably in Swift 3. Remind me to check again for Swift 4 :)

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov Correct; `static` variables cannot use the `lazy` keyword's pattern of initialization. Instead, something like this might work for you: https://gist.github.com/BenLeggiero/d3d87fcfa0e3ac160df1ef6386ff676b

Comment: Is this a current bug in Swift 4? Or was this removed on purpose?  If so, where can I find documentation explaining the change

Comment: This no longer works Swift 3.2 compiled with Xcode 9.1

Comment: [Swift 3.2 is just Swift 4 compiled with Swift 3 syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Compatibility.html), so it will mostly have the same behaviors (like this).

Comment: I think I accidentally used this bug exploit... Thought it was very odd that long standing code only recently began causing crashes (recently updated to Swift 4). Are there strong advantages to the solution you linked to in your edit vs the accepted solution? Accepted solution seems to fit my needs, the one you linked to seems overly complex and I don't see the advantage of it.

Comment: @JakeT. I know how you feel; I was upset to learn that this behavior which I mostly approve of was actually a bug. Once I did, I went into our codebase, created a `ResettableLazy` struct, and used it in place of everywhere we were using `lazy`. As it turns out, PBosman seems to have done nearly the exact same thing, so I updated my answer to endorse his, since it's practically the same solution I came up with independently. The advantage over the accepted is that it's encapsulated in an easily-usable pattern, decreasing the amount of typing (or copy-pasting) needed to get the same behavior.

Comment: @Ben Leggiero I appreciate the endorsement :) although, as I mentioned in my answer, I'm not totally happy with my version. I'd be interested to see what you got if you'd be willing to share it?

Comment: @PhlippieBosman What I wrote is copyrighted to the company I work for, but I'll be happy to write a version for SO in my spare time :) Would you like me to put it in an answer of my own, or yours?

Comment: @BenLeggiero Since it's your version, I think it would be appropriate to put in yours :)

Comment: @BenLeggiero Awesome answer!

Comment: I tried that solution but couldn't get it to run because my  property depends on another property of the same class (think about a `sortedArray` lazy property that returns the sorted values of a Set). Swift complains about the usage of self. David's "manual" solution works fine in this case.

Comment: @OrtwinGentz could you post a SSCCE? I wanna know what broke; maybe my solution could still work

Comment: @OrtwinGentz - you could use a lazy var structure, which allows you to reference self;        private lazy var width: ResettableLazy<CGFloat> = {
        return ResettableLazy { return self.collectionView?.bounds.width ?? 0 }
    }()

Comment: @SomaMan No, in this case, I needed it in a class.

Comment: Getting error with Xcode 13: Generic struct 'ResettableLazy' cannot be used as an attribute

Comment: @Ramis I've made [a ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1151916/ramis) and I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: I think if you try to use a property wrapper you cannot assign `self` to the delegate as in the question. Propery wrappers are inited before self is available. So conformer to the delegate cannot be self for this solution to work.

Answer (score 10):

EDIT: As per Ben Leggiero's answer, lazy vars can be `nil`able in Swift 3.
EDIT 2: Seems like `nil`able lazy vars are no more.

*Very* late to the party, and not even sure if this will be relevant in Swift 3, but here goes. David's answer is good, but if you want to create many lazy nil-able vars, you will have to write a pretty hefty block of code. I'm trying to create an ADT that encapsulates this behaviour. Here's what I've got so far:

```swift
struct ClearableLazy<T> {
    private var t: T!
    private var constructor: () -> T
    init(_ constructor: @escaping () -> T) {
        self.constructor = constructor
    }
    mutating func get() -> T {
        if t == nil {
            t = constructor()
        }
        return t
    }
    mutating func clear() { t = nil }
}
```

You would then declare and use properties like this:

```
var aClient = ClearableLazy(Client.init)
aClient.get().delegate = self
aClient.clear()
```

There are things I don't like about this yet, but don't know how to improve:

- You have to pass a constructor to the initializer, which looks ugly. It has the advantage, though, that you can specify exactly how new objects are to be created.
- Calling `get()` on a property every time you want to use it is terrible. It would be slightly better if this was a computed property, not a function, but computed properties cannot be mutating.
- To eliminate the need to call `get()`, you have to extend every type you want to use this for with initializers for `ClearableLazy`.

If someone feels like picking it up from here, that would be awesome.

Comment: This is essentially what I do in Swift 4, now

Answer (score 5):

This allows setting the property to `nil` to force reinitialization:

```
private var _recordedFileURL: NSURL!

/// Location of the recorded file
private var recordedFileURL: NSURL! {
    if _recordedFileURL == nil {
        let file = "recording\(arc4random()).caf"
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent(file)
        NSLog("FDSoundActivatedRecorder opened recording file: %@", url)
        _recordedFileURL = url
    }
    return _recordedFileURL
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5.1**:

```
class Game {
    private var _scores: [Double]? = nil

    var scores: [Double] {
        if _scores == nil {
            print("Computing scores...")
            _scores = [Double](repeating: 0, count: 3)
        }
        return _scores!
    }

    func resetScores() {
        _scores = nil
    }
}
```

Here is how to use:

```
var game = Game()
print(game.scores)
print(game.scores)
game.resetScores()
print(game.scores)
print(game.scores)
```

This produces the following output:

```
Computing scores...
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Computing scores...
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

**Swift 5.1 and Property Wrapper**

```
@propertyWrapper
class Cached<Value: Codable> : Codable {
    var cachedValue: Value?
    var setter: (() -> Value)?

    // Remove if you don't need your Value to be Codable    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case cachedValue
    }

    init(setter: @escaping () -> Value) {
        self.setter = setter
    }

    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get {
            if cachedValue == nil {
                cachedValue = setter!()
            }
            return cachedValue!
        }
        set { cachedValue = nil }
    }

}

class Game {
    @Cached(setter: {
        print("Computing scores...")
        return [Double](repeating: 0, count: 3)
    })
    var scores: [Double]
}
```

We reset the cache by setting it to any value:

```
var game = Game()
print(game.scores)
print(game.scores)
game.scores = []
print(game.scores)
print(game.scores)
```

Comment: Look at the property wrapper alternative. The syntax is now much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

There are some good answers here.
 Resetting a lazy var is indeed, desirable in a lot of cases.

I think, you can also define a closure to create client and reset lazy var with this closure. Something like this:

```
class ClientSession {
    class func shared() -> ClientSession {
        return ClientSession()
    }
}

class Client {
    let session:ClientSession
    init(_ session:ClientSession) {
        self.session = session
    }
}

class Test {
    private let createClient = {()->(Client) in
        var _aClient = Client(ClientSession.shared())
        print("creating client")
        return _aClient
    }

    lazy var aClient:Client = createClient()
    func resetClient() {
        self.aClient = createClient()
    }
}

let test = Test()
test.aClient // creating client
test.aClient

// reset client
test.resetClient() // creating client
test.aClient
```

Answer (score 2):

If the objective is to re-initialize a lazy property but not necessarily set it to nil, Building from Phlippie Bosman and Ben Leggiero, here is something that avoids conditional checks every time the value is read:

```
public struct RLazy<T> {
    public var value: T
    private var block: () -> T
    public init(_ block: @escaping () -> T) {
        self.block = block
        self.value = block()
    }
    public mutating func reset() {
        value = block()
    }
}
```

To test:

```
var prefix = "a"
var test = RLazy { () -> String in
    return "\(prefix)b"
}

test.value         // "ab"
test.value = "c"   // Changing value
test.value         // "c"
prefix = "d"
test.reset()       // Resetting value by executing block again
test.value         // "db"
```

Answer (score 0):

I made `@David Berry's` answer into a property wrapper. Works great with UI-components that you want to reload if you need to apply size changes but otherwise want to hold in their configured state.

```
@propertyWrapper class Reloadable<T: AnyObject> {
  
  private let initializer:  (() -> T)
  private var _wrappedValue: T?
  var wrappedValue: T {
    if _wrappedValue == nil {
      _wrappedValue = initializer()
    }
    return _wrappedValue!
  }
  
  init(initializer: @escaping (() -> T)) {
    self.initializer = initializer
  }
  
  func nuke() {
    _wrappedValue = nil
  }
}
```

Here's an example with a `CAShapeLayer`. Set you variable like so:

```
@Reloadable<CAShapeLayer>(initializer: {
   Factory.ShapeLayer.make(fromType: .circle(radius: Definitions.radius, borderWidth: Definitions.borderWidth)) // this factory call is just what I use personally to build my components
}) private var circleLayer
```

and when you want to reload your view just call:

```swift
_circleLayer.nuke()
```

Then you can use the `var circleLayer` as you normally would in your re-layout routine, upon which it will get re-initialized.

PS: I made a gist for the file I use in my own project: https://gist.github.com/erikmartens/b34a130d11b62400ab13a59a6c3dbd91

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a pretty bad code smell. Something strange is going on with:

```
var _aClient = Clinet(ClinetSession.shared())
```

What is `ClinetSession.shared()`?

This looks like a static function that returns a new instance of `ClinetSession` on every call.

So no wonder you are not seeing changes to this object. It seems like a broken singleton to me.

```
class ClinetSession {
    static func shared() -> Self {
        ClinetSession()
    }
}
```

Try doing this instead:

```
class ClinetSession {
    static let shared = ClinetSession()
    
    var value: Int = 0
}
```

Now if you change `ClinetSession` `value` you will see it.

There's no need for a lazy property that can be reset here as far as I can tell.

Here's a fully working example. BTW if you don't own `ClinetSession` then write a wrapper to control this.

```
class Clinet {
    let clinetSession: ClinetSession
    init(_ clinetSession: ClinetSession) {
        self.clinetSession = clinetSession
    }
    
    var delegate: P?
}

class ClinetSession {
    static let shared = ClinetSession()
    var value = 0
}

protocol P { }

struct Test: P {
    lazy var aClient:Clinet = {
        var _aClient = Clinet(ClinetSession.shared)
        _aClient.delegate = self
        return _aClient
    }()
    
    mutating func updateSession() {
        aClient.clinetSession.value = 10
    }
    
}

var test = Test()
test.updateSession()
print(test.aClient.clinetSession.value)

// prints 10
```

Note: If you don't want to use a singleton then don't use `shared()` as the constructor as this is a convention. But then it's up to you to make sure you pass in the same reference as the one you want to mutate. That's your job to manage. The singleton just makes sure there is only 1 instance so this becomes simpler but has its trade offs.