# How does this function/variable work?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the following code to retrieve `NSURLCredentials`:

```
let credentials: NSURLCredential? = {
    let loginProtectionSpace = NSURLProtectionSpace(host: host, port: 0, protocol: NSURLProtectionSpaceHTTP, realm: nil, authenticationMethod: NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault)
    let credentials = NSURLCredentialStorage.sharedCredentialStorage().defaultCredentialForProtectionSpace(loginProtectionSpace)
    return credentials
}()
```

This is called when the user opens the app. The credentials returned are nil. Then I set these credentials and try to print credentials out again and it's still nil. However, if I restart the app, the printed credentials are there. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lazy variable. The code gets executed **once** when you first access the property. After that the initially returned value is "remembered" and returned on future calls.

If you set the credentials yourself in the `NSURLCredentialStorage` then on the next start of the app the first access of the property once again executes the code and retrieves the stored credentials. Note that during the run where you first set the credentials up the actual 3 lines of code retrieving the credentials from the storage are not executed a second time and therefore during that run of the app the property still is `nil` while there actually is a value in the storage. A similar thing will happen if you *modify* the existing credentials - during the run where you change them, the `credentials` will still hold a reference to the previous ones.

If you want to be able to requery the store, you should either

- create a function for this instead of a lazy variable
- or take a look at this answer: [Re-initialize a lazy initialized variable in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072597/re-initialize-a-lazy-initialized-variable-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because credentials is immutable. The code block gets executed once to assign credentials its value. Which is why it has the credentials after you restarted the app.