# Lazy stored property in Swift

Tags: swift, lazy-evaluation

I am having some confusion in lazy stored property. 
I read many tutorials and found this, but I could not understand this in real scenario.
Can anyone please clear out few things,

1. A lazy stored property is a property whose initial value is not calculated until the first time it is used...
2. You must always declare a lazy property as a variable (with the var keyword), because its initial value may not be retrieved until after instance initialization completes...
3. Lazy properties are useful when the initial value for a property is dependent on outside factors whose values are not known until after an instance’s initialization is complete.
4. Where should we use lazy stored property

Thanks

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with lazy stored properties? These statements are very clear in their meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mike Buss wrote an article about lazy initialization in Swift http://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/

One example of when to use lazy initialization is when the **initial value for a property is not known until after the object is initialized** or when the **computation of the property is computationally expensive**.

Here are two examples for both cases from the post:

In the first example we don't know which value personalized greeting should have. We need to wait until the object is initialized to know the correct greeting for this person.

```
class Person {

var name: String

lazy var personalizedGreeting: String = {
    [unowned self] in
    return "Hello, \(self.name)!"
    }()

init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

The second example covers the case of an expensive computation. Imagine a MathHelper class which should give you values for pi and other important constants. You don't need to calculate all constants if you only use a subset of them.

```
class MathHelper {

lazy var pi: Double = {
    // Calculate pi to a crazy number of digits
    return resultOfCalculation
    }()

}
```

Comment: How to change personalizedGreeting If I change name?? In same code..

Comment: You may want to take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072597/re-initialize-a-lazy-initialized-variable-in-swift). You have multiple ways to trigger a reinitialization of your lazy attributes.

Answer (score 4):

Explained well!! I want to add a simple example to understand it in a better way.

Lazy property is a stored property whose memory will be allocated only when the variable is actually used.

```
class Car{
    lazy var brand: String = "BMW" // Memory not allocated
}

let aCar = Car()
print(aCar.brand) // Memory allocated as it is getting used here
```