# How to clear value from lazy var in swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am using lazy var in my application. Lazy var initialized only once. When I remove the application from tray then it will clear and initialize with new values. Can we clear lazy var on foreground state?
How to clear value from lazy var in swift iOS?

Comment: For swift3, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40847994/5555803) works.

Comment: I'm also using the ClearableLazy solution from the linked post in the comment ^^^ above.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is `lazy vars` are not constants. You can always set values inside them. They just get initialized when they are needed, and once they have values inside them, they return that value. Hence, the use of closures to "create" the value.

Lets use this info, to play with lazy var in this fashion. Here, we have used another lazy var closure to capture an integer stored property value and successfully reassigned it to the lazy variable.

```
class Test {

    var fooValue:Int = 20

    lazy var foo = {() -> Int in
        print("foo called")
        return self.fooValue*3
    }

    lazy var value:Int = foo()
}

let test = Test()
test.value // foo called
test.value // prints 60

test.fooValue = 40
test.value = test.foo() // foo called
test.value // prints 120
```