# Apple Page Control sample code gives black screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, lazy-loading, uiscrollviewdelegate

Ive downloaded Apple's [PageControl Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) to try to learn how to create lazily loaded pages as the user scrolls. However right out of the box as I scroll the picutres disappear and I get a black screen. Is that supposed to happen is there an error in the code.

[image: page control black screen]

Comment: Works fine for me... Did you make any edits? The sample uses Swift 4 -- did you auto-convert it to a later Swift version?

Comment: By the way... that's a bad example. It doesn't handle device rotation properly.

Comment: @DonMag I haven't made any edits I used the project as is. I've noticed it occurs while swiping fast. I agree it is not the best example but is provided by apple

Comment: Two things worth noting.... 1) That example is out of date, and no longer being updated, and 2) No APple ***example*** code should be considered production-level code. They are examples to get demonstrate ideas.

Comment: @DonMag thank you for your advise are there more relevant examples you could recommend that would be better suited for demonstrating this technique?

Comment: Based on the description of what you're trying to do - in this and your other very similar questions - I still think `UIPageViewController` is the way to go. I know you've commented that you had trouble tracking the pages, but there is plenty of discussion out there on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit the code before running the app?

I was able to reproduce your problem by commenting out the `_ = setupInitialPages` call in the viewDidLayoutSubviews method call. Uncommented, the app works fine.

[image]

The thing to remember with lazy loading vars is they are not populated until called, that's the whole point of lazy loading. If there's no reference to the lazy loaded variable, it won't be instantiated and will result in what you saw in your test.

The syntax for a lazy loaded var is:

`lazy var someVarName: the variable type e.g. Int, UIIMage, String... whatever = {
 // Code in here to populate the variable
return variable with the declared type
}()`

You need to make certain the return of the call to the lazy var matches the type. Also keep in mind, a lazy var while called a variable, once set doesn't change and is more like a constant in that regard. There are some work arounds, but they've already been addressed here... [Re-initialize a lazy initialized variable in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072597/re-initialize-a-lazy-initialized-variable-in-swift)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer I have not changed the code from the downloaded project. I've noticed this problem occurs while swiping fast through the pages. I believe the problem is related to lazily loading the pages. However I am unsure how to fix it.