# Is it possible to exclude certain property (Like class type) from being copied during struct copy?

Tags: swift

I have the following struct, which contains class.

```
import Foundation

func generateRichText(body: String?) -> NSMutableAttributedString? {
    if body == nil {
        return nil
    }

    // TODO: Some complex logic to decorate body string will be added soon...

    let myAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: body!)
    return myAttrString
}

struct Note {
    var body: String?

    // Technique described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25073176/72437
    var bodyAsRichText: NSMutableAttributedString? {
        mutating get {
            if (cachedBodyAsRichText == nil) {
                cachedBodyAsRichText = generateRichText(body: body)
            }
            return cachedBodyAsRichText
        }
    }

    // TODO: This is a class. I don't want it to be copied over during struct copy.
    // If it is copied during struct copy, both struct will be sharing the same
    // class instance.
    private var cachedBodyAsRichText: NSMutableAttributedString?
}

var note = Note()
note.body = "hello"
print("note.bodyAsRichText = \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(note.bodyAsRichText!).toOpaque())")

var note_copy = note
print("note_copy.bodyAsRichText = \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(note_copy.bodyAsRichText!).toOpaque())")
```

For the above code, the output will be

```
note.bodyAsRichText = 0x000055c035cfce70
note_copy.bodyAsRichText = 0x000055c035cfce70
```

What my desired output is, different struct instance, should be having their very own class instance (`cachedBodyAsRichText`)

Hence, is there a way, to exclude `cachedBodyAsRichText` from being copied over, during struct copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is incomplete. Here is a complete and correct solution.

```
struct Note {
    var body: String = "" {
        didSet {
            cachedBodyAsRichText = nil
        }
    }

    var bodyAsRichText: NSAttributedString {
        mutating get {
            if (cachedBodyAsRichText == nil) {
                cachedBodyAsRichText = generateRichText(body: body)
            }
            return cachedBodyAsRichText!.copy() as! NSAttributedString
        }
    }

    private var cachedBodyAsRichText: NSAttributedString? = nil
}
```

You need to clear out the cache every time the body is modified. Once you do that, it won't matter if the object is shared among structs.

Comment: I don't think the solution is correct, as `generateRichText` will be triggered everytime `bodyAsRichText` properties is being accessed. It losses the laziness.

Comment: Also, why does copy is required for `cachedBodyAsRichText`? Isn't `NSAttributedString` is immutable class?

Comment: The `copy()` is required because otherwise the object you would be allowing access to would be an `NSMutableAttributedString` that is part of the internal state of the type. Any outside code would then be able to cast the object back into an `NSMutableAttributedString` and mutate it and you don't don't that object mutated. The copy is required to keep the memory private.

Comment: I added the missing `if` check.

Comment: No. What I mean, what if I don't use `NSMutableAttributedString` at all but solely using `NSAttributedString` (Even `generateRichText` will return `NSAttributedString`) ? Since `NSAttributedString` is immutable, isn't it is safe to be shared across different struct instance?

Comment: Sure, if you don't create an `NSMutableAttributedString` inside the `generateRichText(body:)` function then you won't need the `copy()`.